# Date picker and list picker (multiple time zones) to create a scheduled date string

Tags: ios, objective-c

On the UI side of this project, there is a date picker and list picker intended to allow users to select a future time and date for specific time zones to schedule an alert to be broadcasted by voice, SMS, email, etc. Unfortunately, though, the GMT offset does not correctly adjust. For instance, an alert scheduled for Berlin, Germany (GMT+0200) for June 7, 2017, 17:33 actually yields the next day at 02:30 Berlin time.

> 2017-06-08 00:33:00 +0200

*1. Would anyone know what may cause this discrepancy and how to
    correct it for all time zones?*

*2. What steps are necessary to adjust all the scheduled
    times to Central Daylight Time?*

[Screenshot of New Alert View Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3cuq.png)

In the NewAlertTableViewController.m, this function updates the date picker label:

```
- (void) updateDateLabel {
    NSDate *now                  = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *scheduledDate        = self.datePicker.date;
    if ([scheduledDate isToday] && scheduledDate.hour <= now.hour && scheduledDate.minute <= now.minute) {
        self.dateLabel.text      = NSLocalizedString(@"Now", @"label for time an alert is scheduled to be sent");
        self.sendButton.title    = NSLocalizedString(@"Send Alert", @"button label for sending an alert");
        self.alert.sendNow       = YES;
    } else if ([scheduledDate isToday]) {
        self.dateLabel.text      = [NSString stringWithFormat: NSLocalizedString(@"Today, %@", @"label for time an alert is scheduled to be sent"), [scheduledDate stringWithDateStyle: NSDateFormatterNoStyle                                                                                                                                                                       timeStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle]];
        self.sendButton.title    = NSLocalizedString(@"Save Alert", @"button label for saving an alert");
        self.alert.sendNow       = NO;
    } else {
        self.dateLabel.text      = [scheduledDate stringWithDateStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle
                                                            timeStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
        self.sendButton.title    = NSLocalizedString(@"Save Alert", @"button label for saving an alert");
        self.alert.sendNow       = NO;
    }
    self.alert.scheduledDate     = scheduledDate;
    DDLogInfo(@"Date Picker: %@", scheduledDate);
}
```

Also in the NewAlertTableViewController.m, we have this delegate to handle the time zone picker view:

```
- (void) pickerView: (UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent: (NSInteger)component {
    NSString *timeZone;
    NSString *timeZoneCity;
    NSDateFormatter *systemTimeZoneFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    systemTimeZoneFormatter.timeZone         = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    systemTimeZoneFormatter.dateFormat       = @"Z";
    NSString *systemTimeZoneOffset           = [systemTimeZoneFormatter stringFromDate: [NSDate date]];
    switch (row) {
        case 0:
            timeZone     = (@"GMT%@", systemTimeZoneOffset);
            timeZoneCity = @"Device Default";
            break;
        case 1:
            timeZone     = @"GMT+02:00";
            timeZoneCity = @"Berlin";
            break;
        case 2:
            timeZone     = @"GMT+01:00";
            timeZoneCity = @"London";
            break;
        case 3:
            timeZone     = @"GMT-04:00";
            timeZoneCity = @"New York";
            break;
        case 4:
            timeZone     = @"GMT-05:00";
            timeZoneCity = @"Chicago";
            break;
        case 5:
            timeZone     = @"GMT-06:00";
            timeZoneCity = @"Denver";
            break;
        case 6:
            timeZone     = @"GMT-07:00";
            timeZoneCity = @"Los Angeles";
            break;
        case 7:
            timeZone     = @"GMT-08:00";
            timeZoneCity = @"Anchorage";
            break;
        case 8:
            timeZone     = @"GMT-10:00";
            timeZoneCity = @"Honolulu";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [self updateTimeZone: timeZone];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: timeZone forKey: @"timeZonePreference"];
    DDLogInfo(@"Time Zone Picker: %@, %@", timeZone, timeZoneCity);
    _timeZoneLabel.text = timeZoneCity;
}
```

Yet again in the NewAlertTableViewController.m, this function updates the time zone:

```
- (void) updateTimeZone: (id)timeZone {
    self.now                     = [NSDate date];    
    self.calendar                = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    [self.calendar setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName: timeZone]];
    NSCalendarUnit units         = NSCalendarUnitHour;
    NSDateComponents *components = [self.calendar components: units fromDate: self.now];
    self.hours                   = (int)[components hour];
    self.alert.calendar          = self.calendar;
}
```

In the Alert.m, we have this string that gets sent as a parameter to our CreateAlert.aspx endpoint. **Ideally**, we'd prefer all strings adjusted to **Central Daylight Time** (to match our server in Houston, TX) or at least Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

```
- (NSString *)scheduledDateString { // This method solely uses the scheduledDate
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat       = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z";
    dateFormatter.timeZone         = self.calendar.timeZone;
    NSString *dateString           = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: self.scheduledDate];
    DDLogInfo(@"Scheduled Date: %@", dateString);
    return dateString;
}
```

Comment: At the top of your `updateDateLabel` method, you have this line: `NSDate *scheduledDate = self.datePicker.date;` ... Do you realize that, regardless of what is displayed on the picker, you are getting a *reference time* and not a "local" time?

Comment: @DonMag -- Thanks for looking at this! How would I get a "local" time instead?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code to play with:

```
// User-selected Time Zone city
// using "Europe/Berlin" for this example
NSString *timeZoneName = @"Europe/Berlin";
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:timeZoneName];

// User-selected Date/Time (from the UIDatePicker)
NSDate *selDate = _datePicker.date;

// Current NSCalendar
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

// get all date components from the user-selected Date/Time
NSDateComponents *localComponents = [calendar components:-1 fromDate:selDate];

// set the Calendar to use the user-selected Time Zone
[calendar setTimeZone: timeZone];

// set the components with the values from localComponents
NSDateComponents *timeZoneComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[timeZoneComponents setYear:    [localComponents year]];
[timeZoneComponents setMonth:   [localComponents month]];
[timeZoneComponents setDay:     [localComponents day]];
[timeZoneComponents setHour:    [localComponents hour]];
[timeZoneComponents setMinute:  [localComponents minute]];
[timeZoneComponents setSecond:  [localComponents second]];

// get a NSDate object based on the user-selected Date/Time and Time Zone
// Note: if you print the default description of this date, it will show UTC value
NSDate *desiredDateTime = [calendar dateFromComponents:timeZoneComponents];
NSLog(@"%@", desiredDateTime);
```

The key thing to remember is that a NSDate object is the same whether you are in London, New York, Houston, Honolulu, Tokyo, Berlin, etc, etc. The only difference is how it is displayed.

For example: Right now, it is almost 5:00 pm. But wait, when you read this, it is probably around **4:00 pm**!!! How can that be? Well, I look at `[NSDate date];` right now, I see "2017-06-07 20:55:56 +0000" - because that is the "absolute" date/time.

So, play with this code sample... try out different time zones (make sure you get the names right)... see if it all makes sense.

If I've done this right (it's possible I have a mistake or two here)... If you select Friday, June 16 at 10:00 am in your date picker (regardless of where in the world *you* are), and then run this code, the final `NSLog()` line *should* print:

```
2017-06-16 08:00:25 +0000
```

Because UTC is 2-hours earlier than Berlin time.

Comment: Danke, grazie, thanks, gracias! My iOS experience was mostly in Swift, so it's been a trial getting fluent with Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to savvy suggestions from **@DonMag**, I'm in the home stretch! Got perfect NSDates now with this new NewAlertTableViewController.m time zone picker view delegate:

```
- (void) pickerView: (UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent: (NSInteger)component {
    NSString *timeZoneName;
    NSString *timeZoneLabel;
    NSDateFormatter *systemTimeZoneFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    systemTimeZoneFormatter.timeZone         = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    systemTimeZoneFormatter.dateFormat       = @"VVVV";
    NSString *systemTimeZoneOffset           = [systemTimeZoneFormatter stringFromDate: [NSDate date]];
    switch (row) {
        case 0:
            timeZoneName  = ("%@", systemTimeZoneOffset);
            timeZoneLabel = @"Device Default";
            break;
        case 1:
            timeZoneName  = @"Europe/Berlin";
            timeZoneLabel = @"Berlin";
            break;
        case 2:
            timeZoneName  = @"Europe/London";
            timeZoneLabel = @"London";
            break;
        case 3:
            timeZoneName  = @"America/New_York";
            timeZoneLabel = @"New York";
            break;
        case 4:
            timeZoneName  = @"America/Chicago";
            timeZoneLabel = @"Chicago";
            break;
        case 5:
            timeZoneName  = @"America/Denver";
            timeZoneLabel = @"Denver";
            break;
        case 6:
            timeZoneName  = @"America/Los_Angeles";
            timeZoneLabel = @"Los Angeles";
            break;
        case 7:
            timeZoneName  = @"America/Anchorage";
            timeZoneLabel = @"Anchorage";
            break;
        case 8:
            timeZoneName  = @"Pacific/Honolulu";
            timeZoneLabel = @"Honolulu";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [self updateTimeZone: timeZoneName];
    _timeZoneLabel.text                  = timeZoneLabel;
    NSTimeZone *timeZone                 = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName: timeZoneName];
    DDLogInfo(@"Time Zone Picker: %@", timeZoneName);
    NSDate *datePickerSelection          = _datePicker.date;
    NSCalendar *calendar                 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *localComponents    = [calendar components: -1 fromDate: datePickerSelection];
    [calendar setTimeZone: timeZone];
    NSDateComponents *timeZoneComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [timeZoneComponents setYear:    [localComponents year]];
    [timeZoneComponents setMonth:   [localComponents month]];
    [timeZoneComponents setDay:     [localComponents day]];
    [timeZoneComponents setHour:    [localComponents hour]];
    [timeZoneComponents setMinute:  [localComponents minute]];
    [timeZoneComponents setSecond:  [localComponents second]];
    _desiredDateTime                     = [calendar dateFromComponents: timeZoneComponents];
    DDLogInfo(@"Desired Date: %@", _desiredDateTime);
}
```